# Sort data (order by) before group by in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I want to group below data from `sub_prd_id`. but before that i need order data from **max** `created_at`.

I wrote query as below.

```
select * FROM prd_data group by sub_prd_id order by created_at desc
```

But this query not returned what i need. for example, according to below data, after query executes, result should be as below,

```
id  name    sub_prd_id  created_at
4   Grape     10            2013-04-28 03:11:55
6   Banana    11            2013-04-28 03:23:14
7   Pineapple 12            2013-04-28 03:23:44
```

Here is Table Structure with data.

```
id  name    sub_prd_id  created_at
2   Apple     10            2013-04-28 03:04:51
3   Orange    10            2013-04-28 03:08:19
4   Grape     10            2013-04-28 03:11:55
5   Mango     11            2013-04-28 03:22:48
6   Banana    11            2013-04-28 03:23:14
7   Pineapple 12            2013-04-28 03:23:44
```

Answer (score 6):

What you're trying to accomplish is known as a [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html), which can't be achieved using `ORDER BY`.  Instead, one must find the `MAX()` and then join the result back to the table:

```
SELECT prd_data.* FROM prd_data NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   sub_prd_id, MAX(created_at) created_at
  FROM     prd_data
  GROUP BY sub_prd_id
) t
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d3cc/1/0).

Answer (score 2):

Your hunch was correct. This will so it:

```
select * from
  (select * from prd_data order by created_at desc) x
group by sub_prd_id
```

Note that this is a mysql only solution, but since the question was tagged mysql that should be OK. Mysql has special functionality regarding group by when only *some* of the non-aggregated columns are grouped-by: whereas all other databases disallow this, mysql returns the *first* row encountered for each unique group by combination. By sorting *before* grouping, you get the rows with the latest created_at value for each sub_prd_id.

Comment: For the benefit of others, I'll link to [our previous debate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13452567) on this issue.  I maintain that one cannot *rely* on MySQL to return the "first row encountered" as you suggest it will do in your answer: indeed, the developers have very explicitly documented that the row that will be returned is *indeterminate*.

Comment: @eggyal yes, I recall us butting heads previously, but the fact is this works EVERY TIME! As I said previously, I defy you to create an SQLFiddle that shows behaviour other than what I claim; that it returns the FIRST row, not a random row. If you're so sure, I look forward to your sqlfiddle

Comment: @Bohemian There is a extra `(` in your query.

Comment: @Bishan Thanks for picking that up. Fixed now :)

Comment: This relies on undocumented behaviour. It may work EVERY TIME, but the fact remains that a future version of MySQL might behave differently! There's no advantage to this method in terms of performance, scalability, or portability so I'd be tempted to reject it favour of a documented method.

Comment: @Strawberry it is "unsupported" but it works and has done so for many versions. The reason I like it is the simplicity, brevity and legibility of the query if you use it (compare my query with the other answer's query for example)

Comment: @Strawberry: In fairness, even documented features could change in a future version - I don't perceive that to be the real risk here; rather, there may well be corner cases that cause it to break in existing versions. Long ago, I asked [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/28913) on [dba.se] to try and uncover such corner cases: [Rolando](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/29321) makes some good observations about how easily corner cases can arise, and [ypercube points out](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/28913#comment49805_28913) that just such corner cases do exist in MariaDB.

Comment: @eggyal My point is that if a documented/supported method changed, then that change would also be documented!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM prd_data x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT sub_prd_id
            , MAX(created_at) max_created_at 
         FROM prd_data 
        GROUP 
           BY sub_prd_id
     ) y 
    ON y.sub_prd_id = x.sub_prd_id 
   AND y.max_created_at = x.created_at;
```

Answer (score 0):

Query (will always work but is slower than other query):

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d3cc/3)**

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM prd_data t1
WHERE t1.id = (SELECT t2.id
               FROM prd_data t2
               WHERE t2.sub_prd_id= t1.sub_prd_id
               ORDER BY t2.created_at DESC
               LIMIT 1)
```

Other Query (will work only if sub_prd_id has one MAX value):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM prd_data t1
WHERE t1.created_at = (SELECT MAX(t2.created_at)
                       FROM prd_data t2
                       WHERE t2.sub_prd_id= t1.sub_prd_id)
```

Result:

```
| ID |      NAME | SUB_PRD_ID |                   CREATED_AT |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  4 |     Grape |         10 | April, 28 2013 03:11:55+0000 |
|  6 |    Banana |         11 | April, 28 2013 03:23:14+0000 |
|  7 | Pineapple |         12 | April, 28 2013 03:23:44+0000 |
```