# MySQL A Left Join B table Group BY A.id but order by B.id

Tags: mysql

Table A

```
id(UNIQUE)  name
   1       tomato
   2       potato
```

Table B

```
id  AID   buy_date   buy_money
 6   1   2015-01-01    100
 7   1   2015-02-02    200
```

I want to select all A's record filtered with name, and with the latest buy_date and buy_money like this:

```
A.id  A.name  B.buy_date  B.buy_money
 1    tomato  2015-02-02     200
 2    potato     NULL        NULL
```

How can I write the SQL script? I have tried:

```
select A.id, A.name, MAX(B.buy_date)
from A left join B on A.id = B.AID
where A.name like '%to%'
Group by A.id
```

But this only get the right buy_date, but no buy_money.

Comment: `SELECT a.*, x.buy_date, x.buy_money FROM a JOIN b x ON b.aid = a.id JOIN (SELECT aid, MAX(buy_date) max_buy_date FROM b GROUP BY aid)y ON y.aid = x.aid AND y.max_buy_date = x.buy_date;`

Comment: @Strawberry is there any simple way with no subquery?

Comment: Yes. But it's slower... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261068/sort-data-order-by-before-group-by-in-mysql/16261079#16261079

works great for me..

Comment: @MunjalMayank I want the matching buy_money in the mean time, not only the buy_date.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bee19b/1

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, t.*
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT B.* 
  FROM B 
  LEFT JOIN B b_
  ON b.AID = b_.AID
    AND b.buy_date<b_.buy_date
  WHERE b_.id IS NULL
) t
ON A.id = t.AID
WHERE A.name LIKE '%to%'
```

Answer (score 0):

2 basic methods here.

Firstly, if the buy date is unique for an AID then you can get the latest buy_date for each AID using a sub query and join that against the B table to get the rest of the details.

Down side of this is that if there are multiple records for an AID with the same buy_date you will get multiple records back

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, B.buy_date, B.buy_money
FROM A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT AID, MAX(buy_date) AS max_buy_date
    FROM B
    GROUP BY AID
) AS sub_B 
ON A.id = sub_B.AID
LEFT OUTER JOIN B
ON B.AID = sub_B.AID
AND B.buy_date = sub_B.max_buy_date
WHERE A.name like '%to%'
```

Second solution is to use GROUP_CONCAT to get all the values back, ordered by buy_date descending, then use SUBSTRING_INDEX to get everything up to the first delimiter. Default delimiter for GROUP_CONCAT is a comma but if you values might contain a comma you can easily change that. Down side of this is that it is forcing a conversion of the date and money fields to strings.

```
SELECT A.id, 
        A.name, 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(B.buy_date ORDER BY B.buy_date DESC), ',', 1),
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(B.buy_money ORDER BY B.buy_date DESC), ',', 1)
FROM A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN B
ON B.AID = A.id
WHERE A.name like '%to%'
GROUP BY A.id, A.name
```