# How can I make order by before group by in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, eloquent

My case is the same as this : [Sort data (order by) before group by in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261068/sort-data-order-by-before-group-by-in-mysql)

I try all answer there and I find the best answer from @Justin

The answer in mysql like this :

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM prd_data t1
WHERE t1.id = (SELECT t2.id
               FROM prd_data t2
               WHERE t2.sub_prd_id= t1.sub_prd_id
               ORDER BY t2.created_at DESC
               LIMIT 1)
```

I had try sql query and it work

But How convert the sql query to laravel eloquent?

I find it difficult to convert the sql query in laravel eloquent. Because the query is very complex

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why would you convert it to eloquent? You can simply create a MySQL view and have eloquent model deal with that view. Hide the complexity of the query. There's nothing to gain if you rewrite this into eloquent honestly.

Comment: @Mjh, What do you mean? Try to answer with the code. Let me easily understand your point

Comment: I thought you were familiar with MySQL and what a view is. I won't be providing copy-paste code for people to use if they don't understand the basic concepts.. I don't think it's productive or worth the effort. I'd suggest you look around to see what a view is, then you'll most likely get what I'm trying to suggest.

Comment: @Mjh, It seems that I am not interested in using view. i want to use eloquent laravel

Comment: Alright, no problem, there's no reason to use simpler, cleaner approach anyway :) good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use DB::select() if you want use sql query

```
DB::select("SELECT t1.* FROM prd_data t1 WHERE t1.id = (SELECT t2.id
           FROM prd_data t2
           WHERE t2.sub_prd_id= t1.sub_prd_id
           ORDER BY t2.created_at DESC
           LIMIT 1)");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$whereClause = DB::table(‘prd_data’)->where(t2.sub_prd_id, t1.sub_prd_id)->orderBy(’t2.created_at’,’desc’)->take(1)->get();

$result = DB::table(‘prd_data')->where(t1.id,$whereCond.id)->get();
```

hope it works :)

Comment: It seems it will be an error. Because it will run `$whereClause` first. While inside `$whereClause`, `t1.sub_prd_id` has no value. I have not tried it yet. But it seems to be an error

Answer (score 0):

->whereRaw('customer_items.customer_item_id IN (select MAX(customer_items.customer_item_id) FROM customer_items GROUP BY customer_items.jan)')

**Use this way**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).